# Como organizar matriz

Tags: php, array

esta sendo feita uma comparação:

esta assim

```
$result3 = array_diff($fetchForm, $items['form_id']);
print_r($result3);

    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [2] => 3
    )

$result2 = array_diff($items['form_id'], $fetchForm);
print_r($result2);

    Array
    (
        [1] => 4
    )
```

para assim

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

Comment: Não estou entendendo a pergunta. E essas arrays que você mostrou, são a entrada do diff?

Comment: estes arrays são as saidas

Comment: Como assim "as" saídas? `array_diff` retorna **uma** array. E qual seriam as entradas então?

Comment: Me parece que faltou a pergunta clara. Edita lá e tenta explicar melhor para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: perdeu sim... mais essa e outra parte mais a frente akela parte não consegui resolver por enquanto ai to desenvolvendo essa ai depois vo voltar la ai vo publicar ele pra ver se vcs podem me da uma mão

Comment: entao sao duas entradas por isso 2 array... na verdade e 1 entrada apenas ai confere com o banco de dados ai separa em 2 array

Comment: Você tem **2** `array_diff`?

Comment: sim... dei uma editada... os diff sao um o inverso do outro

Comment: obrigado pessoal @PapaCharlie resolveu :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*Array-diff*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php), retorna um array contendo todas as entradas de array1 que **não estão** presentes em algum dos outros arrays.

Array-diff vai retornar a KEY e VALUE, por esse motivo você não recebe um array com indices ordenados.

```
$array1 = array("verde", "vermelho", "azul", "amarelo");
$array2 = array("verde", "vermelho");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

**output**: `array( 2 => 'azul' , 3 => 'amarelo' )`

---

Para refazer seu array em ordem, pode usar [*array_values*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

```
$result = array_values( $result );
print_r($result);
```

**output**: `array( 0 => 'azul' , 1 => 'amarelo' )`

Comment: funcionou perfeito, obrigado!!!